# Why is this code giving me error (postgresql JSONB )?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    goods 
WHERE   jsonb_exists_any(params->'sex', array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

> ERROR:  function jsonb_exists_any(jsonb, integer[]) does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT * FROM goods WHERE jsonb_exists_any(params->'sex',
>   ar...

Comment: Probably because the function `jsonb_exists_any()` doesn't exist?

Comment: What is your Postgres version? run `select version()` to find out

Comment: Look the postgres doc                             https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html

Comment: `jsonb_exists_any()` is not a documented `jsonb` function. It *might* be a backing function for some `jsonb` operator, but relying on those names is not a very good idea (they might change over time). Anyway, all `jsonb` operator & function uses `text[]` parameters, not `int[]` ones. Try with `array['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']` (or with explicit casts with `array[...]::text[]`).

Comment: @pozs you can see him explicitly calling it. That sounds like a stretch.

Comment: it expects a text[] -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/38370973/2946008

Answer (score 1):

Call functions that exist, `jsonb_exists_any` does not exist. Why did you think `jsonb_exists_any` existed? Was it just a typo?

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    goods 
WHERE   jsonb_exists_any(params->'sex', array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Find the functions [that exist in the latest version here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

I'm guessing you want this..

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    goods 
WHERE   params->'sex' = ANY(ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Comment: All operators in PostgreSQL have an alias function. `jsonb_exists_any` exists and can be used instead of `?|`

Comment: @Ser where can I find the list of operator aliases in the system catalogues? Also, are they guaranteed to remain the same from version to version?

Comment: They are available using `select * from pg_catalog.pg_operator`. I had an issue to use JSONB operators on Java (Thx JDBC that does not support `?`), but you should never use alias function as they ignore indexes - here is why : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52965488/2294168