# Indexing a jsonb array in Postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I try to set up a GIN index but I do not think my index is used when I run the request, whether I use an operator or a function.

## Environment

In our table we have a JSONB field (`json_aip`) containing a Json that looks like that:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "pdi": {
            "contextInformation": {
                "tags": ["SOME_TAG"]
            },
    },
}
```

Table creation :

```
create table t_aip (
    json_aip jsonb,
    [...]
);

CREATE INDEX idx_aip_tags 
ON t_aip 
USING gin ((json_aip -> 'properties' -> 'pdi' -> 'contextInformation' -> 'tags'));
```

## Operator query

We can't use the operator `?|` as we use JDBC. But rumors indicate I should see my index when I run that type of query.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*)  
FROM storage.t_aip 
WHERE json_aip#>'{properties,pdi,contextInformation,tags}' ?| array['SOME_TAG']
```

Result:

```
  Aggregate

  (cost=27052.16..27052.17 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=488.085..488.087 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on t_aip  (cost=0.00..27052.06 rows=42 width=0) (actual time=0.134..456.978 rows=16502 loops=1)
        Filter: ((json_aip #> '{properties,pdi,contextInformation,tags}'::text[]) ?| '{SOME_TAG}'::text[])
        Rows Removed by Filter: 17511
Planning time: 23.202 ms
Execution

time: 488.449 ms
```

## Functional query

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*)  
FROM storage.t_aip 
WHERE jsonb_exists_any(
    json_aip#>'{properties,pdi,contextInformation,tags}', 
    array['SOME_TAG']
)
```

Result:

```
QUERY PLAN
Aggregate  (cost=27087.00..27087.01 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=369.931..369.933 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on t_aip  (cost=0.00..27052.06 rows=13979 width=0) (actual time=0.173..350.437 rows=16502 loops=1)
        Filter: jsonb_exists_any((json_aip #> '{properties,pdi,contextInformation,tags}'::text[]), '{SOME_TAG}'::text[])
        Rows Removed by Filter: 17511
Planning time: 56.021 ms
Execution time: 370.252 ms
```

There is nothing about the index at all. Any help would be much appreciated !

I think my index is wrong because it considers that at the end of the path `json_aip -> 'properties' -> 'pdi' -> 'contextInformation' -> 'tags'` it index a String whether that's an array. That's my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a general rule that you have to use exactly the same expression both in an index and a query to use the index. With this index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_aip_tags 
ON t_aip 
USING gin ((json_aip#>'{properties,pdi,contextInformation,tags}'));
```

the query will use the index

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT count(*)  
FROM t_aip 
WHERE json_aip#>'{properties,pdi,contextInformation,tags}' ?| array['SOME_TAG']

                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=149.97..149.98 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=27.783..27.783 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on t_aip  (cost=20.31..149.87 rows=40 width=0) (actual time=1.504..25.726 rows=20000 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((json_aip #> '{properties,pdi,contextInformation,tags}'::text[]) ?| '{SOME_TAG}'::text[])
         Heap Blocks: exact=345
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_aip_tags  (cost=0.00..20.30 rows=40 width=0) (actual time=1.455..1.455 rows=20000 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((json_aip #> '{properties,pdi,contextInformation,tags}'::text[]) ?| '{SOME_TAG}'::text[])
```

Note that the GIN index supports also `@>` operator:

```
SELECT count(*)  
FROM t_aip 
WHERE json_aip#>'{properties,pdi,contextInformation,tags}' @> '["SOME_TAG"]'
```

but be careful when searching for more than one tag:

```
SELECT count(*)  
FROM t_aip 
-- this gives objects containing both tags:
-- WHERE json_aip#>'{properties,pdi,contextInformation,tags}' @> '["SOME_TAG", "ANOTHER_TAG"]'
-- and this gives objects with any of two tags:
WHERE json_aip#>'{properties,pdi,contextInformation,tags}' @> ANY(ARRAY['["SOME_TAG"]', '["ANOTHER_TAG"]']::jsonb[])
```

Comment: This is so helpfull ! And this is quite strange but interesting to use the `@>` with the `ANY` keyword to get the same behavior than `?|`

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

I thought the opposite, but in fact **THERE IS** a difference between operators (`?|`) and functions (`jsonb_exists_any`) about index usage, as the index is never used when the query uses (jsonb) functions.

You can get more about it here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91007

That was the other question of this topic.

EDIT2:

You can create function alias that can use index and be used as functions in your code, like this :

```
-- Define functions that calls the postgres native operator, to overpass the JDBC issue related to question mark
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rs_jsonb_exists_all(jsonb, text[])
RETURNS bool AS
'SELECT $1 ?& $2' LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rs_jsonb_exists(jsonb, text)
RETURNS bool AS
'SELECT $1 ? $2' LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rs_jsonb_exists_any(jsonb, text[])
RETURNS bool AS
'SELECT $1 ?| $2' LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```