# What's the correct way to escape the ? character in a JDBC PreparedStatement when using Oracle 12c MATCH_RECOGNIZE?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, match-recognize

The following query is correct in Oracle 12c:

```
SELECT *
FROM dual
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  MEASURES a.dummy AS dummy
  PATTERN (a?)
  DEFINE a AS (1 = 1)
)
```

But it doesn't work through JDBC because of the `?` character that is used as a regular expression character, not as a bind variable.

What's the correct way to escape the `?` through JDBC, assuming I want to run this as a `PreparedStatement` with bind variables?

#### Note:

- I've found a discussion on the JDBC spec discuss mailing list, but there's no conclusion to this problem: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdbc-spec-discuss/2013-October/000066.html
- PostgreSQL has similar problems with JSON operators: [How do I use PostgreSQL JSON(B) operators containing a question mark "?" via JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370972/how-do-i-use-postgresql-jsonb-operators-containing-a-question-mark-via-jdb)

Comment: Don't use a `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Let's assume instead of `dual`, I have a super complicated derived table with tons of bind variables in it because SQL injection etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is covered explicitly in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/apxref.htm#CHECHCJH):

> ## `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` Clause
>
> The `?` character is used as a token in `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` clause in Oracle Database 11g and later versions. As the JDBC standard defines the `?` character as a parameter marker, the JDBC Driver and the Server SQL Engine cannot distinguish between different uses of the same token.
>
> In earlier versions of JDBC Driver, if you want to interpret the `?` character as a `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` token and not as a parameter marker, then you must use a `Statement` instead of a `PreparedStatement` and disable escape processing. However, starting from Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2), you can use the `'{\ ... \}'` syntax while using the `?` character, so that the JDBC driver does not process it as a parameter marker and allows the SQL engine to process it.

Comment: If you are putting the escape sequence into a Java string then you need to escape the \ character inside the Java string so the full sequence would be `{\\?\\}`. This is clearer in the [OJDBC documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/JDBC-reference-information.html#GUID-3454411C-5F24-4D46-83A9-5DA0BA704F5D).