# test JOOQ postgres jsonb column for key exists

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jooq

I've got a table `TABLE` that contains a jsonb column named `tags`. The `tags` element in each row may or may not contain a field called `group`.  My goal is to group by `tags.group` for all rows where `tags` contains a `group` field. Like the following postgres query:

```
select tags->>'group' as group, sum(n) as sum
from TABLE
where tags ? 'group'
group by tags->>'group';
```

I'm trying to turn it into JOOQ and cannot find out how to express the `where tags ? 'group'` condition.

For example,

```
val selectGroup = DSL.field("{0}->>'{1}'", String::class.java, TABLE.TAGS, "group")
dsl().select(selectGroup, DSL.sum(TABLE.N))
  .from(TABLE)
  .where(TABLE.TAGS.contains('group'))
  .groupBy(selectGroup)
```

This is equivalent to testing contains condition `@>` in postgres. But I need to do exists condition `?`. How can I express that in JOOQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things worth mentioning here:

#### The `?` operator in JDBC

Unfortunately, there's no good solution to this as `?` is currently strictly limited to be used as a bind variable placeholder in the PostgreSQL JDBC driver. So, even if you could find a way to send that character to the server through jOOQ, the JDBC driver would still misinterpret it.

[A workaround is documented in this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38370973/521799).

#### Plain SQL and string literals

When you're using the [plain SQL templating language](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) in jOOQ, beware that there is a parser that will parse certain tokens of your string, including e.g. comments and string literals. This means that your usage of...

```
DSL.field("{0}->>'{1}'", String::class.java, TABLE.TAGS, "group")
```

is incorrect, as `'{1}'` will be parsed as a string literal and sent to the server as is. If you want to use a variable string literal, do this instead:

```
DSL.field("{0}->>{1}", String::class.java, TABLE.TAGS, DSL.inline("group"))
```

See also [`DSL.inline()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#inline-java.lang.String-)