# Howto expose a native SQL function as a predicate

Tags: jooq

I have a table in my database which stores a list of string values as a jsonb field.

```sql
create table rabbits_json (
  rabbit_id bigserial primary key, 
  name text, 
  info jsonb not null
);

insert into rabbits_json (name, info) values
  ('Henry','["lettuce","carrots"]'),
  ('Herald','["carrots","zucchini"]'),
  ('Helen','["lettuce","cheese"]');
```

I want to filter my rows checking if info contains a given value.
In SQL, I would use [? operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

```sql
select * from rabbits_json where info ? 'carrots';
```

If my googling skills are fine today, I believe that this is not implemented yet in JOOQ:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9997

How can I use a native predicate in my query to write an equivalent query in JOOQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anything that's not supported natively in jOOQ, you should use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/), e.g.

```java
Condition condition = DSL.condition("{0} ? {1}", RABBITS_JSON.INFO, DSL.val("carrots"));
```

Unfortunately, in this specific case, you will run [into this issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38370973/521799). With JDBC `PreparedStatement`, you still cannot use `?` for other usages than bind variables. As a workaround, you can:

- Use `Settings.statementType == STATIC_STATEMENT` to prevent using a `PreparedStatement` in this case
- Use the `jsonb_exists_any` function (not indexable) instead of `?`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38370973/521799